# This site is scraping Stack overflow

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

This page

http://worldhousefinder.com/?p=105224

Is a copy of this question

[Intercept click on content in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085752/intercept-click-on-content-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Also read [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)