# Remove a post from the "Related questions" if it is already linked and can be seen in the "Linked questions"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, related-questions, linked-questions

I've visited [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288908/this-site-is-scraping-stack-overflow) and saw this in the sidebar in the right:

[image: CROPPED_SCREENSHOT]

The same question appears in the "Linked questions" and "Related questions". This shouldn't happen because I don't see any reason why there should be two links to the same question.

Comment: Should be tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] and is valid for MSE (I lack the rep to suggest edits here...)

Comment: [Linked and Related sections contain duplicate links to questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48624/linked-and-related-sections-contain-duplicate-links-to-questions)